# Flutter: InkWell or Gesturedetctor not work inside positioned

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm was try **InkWell**, **GestureDetector** inside postioned:

```
                        Positioned(,
                          right: width * 0.09,
                          top: 38,
                          child: GestureDetector(
                             behavior: HitTestBehavior.deferToChild,
                            onTap: () {
                              log("Testtt);
                            },
                            child: SizedBox(
                              width: 50,
                              height: 30,
                              child: Stack(
                                children: [
                                  const Padding(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                    child: Icon(
                                      Icons.notifications,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      size: 60,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Positioned(
                                    top: 0,
                                    right: 0,
                                    child: Obx(
                                      () => notifikasi.total.value > 0
                                          ? Container(
                                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
                                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                color: Colors.red,
                                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                              ),
                                              constraints: const BoxConstraints(
                                                minWidth: 16,
                                                minHeight: 16,
                                              ),
                                              child: Text(
                                                "${notifikasi.total.value}",
                                                style: const TextStyle(
                                                  color: Colors.white,
                                                  fontSize: 12,
                                                ),
                                                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                              ),
                                            )
                                          : Container(),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
```

But nor work.
I'm was trying to

```
                        InkWell(
                          onTap: () {
                            log("Tesss");
                          },
                          splashColor: Colors.blueAccent,
                          child: Container(
                            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 100, top: 50),
                            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                            alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                            child: const Icon(
                              Icons.notification_add,
                              size: 35,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
```

Clicks successfully, but all areas below the icon are clickable. If right on the icon, it cannot be clicked

[Full Widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEoV8.png)

I'm try create code inkwell, gesture detector, floatingbutton, iconbutton inside postioned.

Comment: can you include a sample full snippet from `Stack` widget.  Stack's bottom widget will on tap event.

Comment: @Md.YeasinSheikh Image on question full widget

Answer (score 0):

You must wrap your widget in a stack so that your widget can easily reposition itself on the screen, otherwise your widget is limited to the space of its parent widget.

Comment: Can you give me example code?